# which datatype i should use for mapping to boolean

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to map a db column to a boolean  in hibernate.Which datatype i should use to map it?

```
tiny int?
```

I will use reverse mapping in netbeans to generate POJOS

Comment: There's a `BOOLEAN` type in MySQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take `BIT(1)` in mysql and `Boolean` in java object

Answer (score 6):

tinyint(1) will map to boolean

bit will map to boolean as well, but when exporting bit with mysqldump will look like '\0' so i recommend tinyint(1) which will look like 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BOOL`/`BOOLEAN` in mysql which is a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on your Database Management System . Examples you can use bit in MS Sql , mysql